# Bokeh Flask Deployment on Google Cloud

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, bokeh

I am trying to deploy my Bokeh Dashboard to Google Cloud via Flask. I am trying to embed the Bokeh Dashboard inside of a Flask website but cannot get it off `localhost` in order to properly deploy it. I have been searching for a canonical example but have yet to see something simple so that I can extrapolate to a more complex system.

The current file structure of my git hub repository looks something like,

```
app.yaml
requirements.txt
bokeh-sliders.py
hello.py
templates/
     hello.html
```

My bokeh-sliders.py file is

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure

# Set up data
N = 200
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
y = np.sin(x)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))


# Set up plot
plot = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=400, title="my sine wave",
              tools="crosshair,pan,reset,save,wheel_zoom",
              x_range=[0, 4*np.pi], y_range=[-2.5, 2.5])

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)


# Set up widgets
text = TextInput(title="title", value='my sine wave')
offset = Slider(title="offset", value=0.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0, step=0.1)
amplitude = Slider(title="amplitude", value=1.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0)
phase = Slider(title="phase", value=0.0, start=0.0, end=2*np.pi)
freq = Slider(title="frequency", value=1.0, start=0.1, end=5.1)


# Set up callbacks
def update_title(attrname, old, new):
    plot.title.text = text.value

text.on_change('value', update_title)

def update_data(attrname, old, new):

    # Get the current slider values
    a = amplitude.value
    b = offset.value
    w = phase.value
    k = freq.value

    # Generate the new curve
    x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
    y = a*np.sin(k*x + w) + b

    source.data = dict(x=x, y=y)

for w in [offset, amplitude, phase, freq]:
    w.on_change('value', update_data)


# Set up layouts and add to document
inputs = widgetbox(text, offset, amplitude, phase, freq)

curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, plot, width=800))
curdoc().title = "Sliders"
```

My hello.py file is,

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort
from bokeh.embed import server_document

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    script=server_document("http://localhost:5006/bokeh-sliders")
    print(script)
    return render_template('hello.html',bokS=script)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My nested hello.html file is,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Website</title>
<style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC:700);
body{
    text-align: center;
}
h1{
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #8ac640;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
 <p>Flask embedding Bokeh test</p>
{{ bokS|indent(4)|safe }}

</body>
</html>
```

I know this might be a bit of code for a MWE but, this is what I have done so far. There is also an app.yaml file and a requirements.txt file but I do not know if they are necessary to answer the question.

If I run `python hello.py` then I can view the interactive document but if I try to deploy the app then I get a 502 Bad Gateway Error. Is there something that I am missing about correctly deploying the Bokeh Dashboard via `server_document`?

**EDIT:**

The shell response when I use `bokeh serve bokeh-sliders.py --allow-websocket-origin=*` is,

```
(hello_world) brycechudomelka@cloudshell:~/mlcdashboard (mlcdashboard)$ bokeh serve bokeh-sliders.py --allow-websocket-origin=*
2019-08-06 12:53:31,636 Starting Bokeh server version 1.3.2 (running on Tornado 6.0.3)
2019-08-06 12:53:31,638 Host wildcard '*' will allow connections originating from multiple (or possibly all) hostnames or IPs. Use non-wildcard values to restrict access explicitly
2019-08-06 12:53:31,642 Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/bokeh-sliders
2019-08-06 12:53:31,643 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 421
2019-08-06 12:55:38,205 302 GET /?authuser=0 (127.0.0.1) 1.20ms
2019-08-06 12:55:38,694 200 GET /bokeh-sliders (127.0.0.1) 332.15ms
2019-08-06 12:55:39,369 404 GET /favicon.ico (127.0.0.1) 0.91ms
2019-08-06 12:55:39,796 101 GET /bokeh-sliders/ws?bokeh-protocol-version=1.0&bokeh-session-id=70lK44usV1edkGRZmGWWpKMVn3DxhOsUlM5xSqqw6p5p (127.0.0.1) 1.38ms
2019-08-06 12:55:39,797 WebSocket connection opened
2019-08-06 12:55:39,798 ServerConnection created
```

So, the Bokeh Serve works but is not embeded and, thus, cannot deploy it.

Comment: Are you whitelisting the domain that will be embedding he Bokeh app with `--allow-websocket-origin`? Is GCP configured to proxy/forward websockets? What is the console output of the Bokeh server when a browser tries to connect? What is the JS console output in a browser when it tries to connect?

Comment: I was following this as a reference, https://gist.github.com/Wildcarde/6841f00f0a0cd52ade09964a0fdb5684, and using ```--allow-websocket-origin=*```.

Comment: Also, I edited my post to include the information you asked about.

Comment: Are those the logs from a real deployment attempt? I'm asking about what happens in in a real deployment. What/where is reporting a 502, exactly? i.e. is there an nginx proxy or similar in front? What does its log show? This seems like a configuration issue, not a code issue, but there's just not enough information here to speculate

Comment: When I deploy everything I get no error. That output is from running ```bokeh serve``` and I visit via Web Preview. The Bad Gateway error is from http://mlcdashboard.appspot.com/

Comment: Is there a tutorial or guide for configuring things properly, i.e. a canonical example

Comment: Things differ wildly by cloud provider. I'm not aware of anything for GCP specifically. That error page is definitely coming from nginx. To diagnose this will absolutely need to see what actual error is showing up in the nginx logs. I'm not sure how to access or configure the nginx proxy on GCP.

Comment: @bigreddot What do you need to help?

Comment: I just stated: the nginx logs. I don't use GCP so I can't help you figure out how to get them. But the actual 502 you are seeing is coming from nginx, so finding the overall answer means seeing why nginx is returning the 502.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you to deploy to Google Cloud Platform you must create a custom flex environment. This means that a Dockerfile must be included. Here is an example of a Git repository that will

Here is the Dockerfile.

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda
ENV BK_VERSION=1.4.0 ENV PY_VERSION=3.7 ENV NUM_PROCS=4 ENV BOKEH_RESOURCES=cdn
RUN apt-get install git bash    
RUN git clone https://github.com/BryceWayne/CMCDashboard.git
RUN cd CMCDashboard 
RUN conda install --yes --quiet python=${PY_VERSION} pyyaml jinja2 bokeh=${BK_VERSION} numpy "nodejs>=8.8" pandas requests scikit-learn matplotlib lxml
RUN conda install -c anaconda lxml
RUN conda clean -ay
EXPOSE 8080
CMD bokeh serve --port 8080 \
    --allow-websocket-origin="*" \
    --num-procs=${NUM_PROCS} \
    CMCDashboard/dashboard.py
```

Here is the app.yaml file.

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

And the dashboard is the same as above, so we can use sliders.py for reference.

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure

# Set up data
N = 200
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
y = np.sin(x)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))


# Set up plot
plot = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=400, title="my sine wave",
              tools="crosshair,pan,reset,save,wheel_zoom",
              x_range=[0, 4*np.pi], y_range=[-2.5, 2.5])

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)


# Set up widgets
text = TextInput(title="title", value='my sine wave')
offset = Slider(title="offset", value=0.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0, step=0.1)
amplitude = Slider(title="amplitude", value=1.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0)
phase = Slider(title="phase", value=0.0, start=0.0, end=2*np.pi)
freq = Slider(title="frequency", value=1.0, start=0.1, end=5.1)


# Set up callbacks
def update_title(attrname, old, new):
    plot.title.text = text.value

text.on_change('value', update_title)

def update_data(attrname, old, new):

    # Get the current slider values
    a = amplitude.value
    b = offset.value
    w = phase.value
    k = freq.value

    # Generate the new curve
    x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
    y = a*np.sin(k*x + w) + b

    source.data = dict(x=x, y=y)

for w in [offset, amplitude, phase, freq]:
    w.on_change('value', update_data)


# Set up layouts and add to document
inputs = widgetbox(text, offset, amplitude, phase, freq)

curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, plot, width=800))
curdoc().title = "Sliders"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm inferring you are trying to deploy this application in App Engine.

Please refer to this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41813131/7806223) to know more about the limitation of using Bokeh and Numpy on App Engine.

Also refer to this documentation to know more about the [limitations on using sockets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/#limitations_and_restrictionsjava_7_runtime_only) in App engine standard.

And this documentation to know more about the **beta** feature of App Engine Flex to allow [Websockets connections](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-websockets-and-session-affinity).

in conclusion, deploying apps which require sockets connections on App Engine could be tricky due to the limitations on persistent connections. It might be better for you to use a Compute Engine Instance to serve your app instead (or Kubernetes depending on your use case, here's an example on how to create a [custom interactive dashboards with Bokeh and BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/bokeh-and-bigquery-dashboards))

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have gone through the Bokeh + BigQuery tutorial and it doesn't work. I followed the tutorial but it seems to not work properly.

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't work properly? Are you stuck in some step? Do you see any error message?